# How to install libtoolize as non-root user

Tags: software-installation, libraries, non-root-user

I'm trying to install software and the autoreconf fails because `libtoolize` is not installed on my system.  I don't have root access on this system, but I need to install `libtoolize`.

How can I install `libtoolize`? What source code package provides this?

Answer (score 30):

The software package is `libtool` : https://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/

Answer (score 17):

This solves the problem:
`sudo apt-get install libtool`

Comment: "I don't have root access on this system".  I interpret this as they don't have the ability to use `sudo` to gain the root privileges necessary to use `apt-get`.

Answer (score 2):

You can download `libtool` from https://ftp.wayne.edu/gnu/libtool/. Unzip it, and build it with make, and if you get something like this error (which you probably will, giving that it is not in your PATH:

```
error: libtoolize not working, re-run with LIBTOOLIZE=/path/to/libtoolize
       LIBTOOLIZE is currently ""
```

You just set that environment variable if you get something like that, or if you don't have the option to set a variable like that, you can just add the binary's folder to your path

EDIT: I don't understand the downvote. He said he didn't have root access, so how could he install the `libtoolize` package